# TOROW equivalent function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to put some UNIQUE values from a COLUMN into a set of ROWS. In Excel I use `ToRow`, but I cannot find an equivalent in Google Sheets. Here was the original question I asked (and was answered), but the answer was related to Excel and now I've uploaded it to Google Sheets and it is not working:

I have an Excel spreadsheet to track a game I play and I'm trying to determine how often I win with a certain character. There is some metadata in the table (like date, location, etc) but the important parts are this:

| Character | Winner |
| --- | --- |
| Yuriko | me |
| Yuriko | Derevi |
| Yuriko | me |
| Yuriko | me |
| Winota | me |
| Winota | Derevi |

I want to be able to have 2 stats columns in my other sheet:

| Yuriko Win % | Winota Win % |
| --- | --- |
| 75% | 50% |

I know how to find the win percentage, but I don't know how to limit my data set by character. Is this possible in Excel?

I'm also happy to use a chart here, if that makes it easier.

Edit: Not the cleanest solution, so if someone has something better, I'm all ears, but here's what I have:

Yuriko Games Played:

```
=COUNTIF('Game Log'!F2:'Game Log'!F500,"Yuriko")
```

Yuriko Wins:

```
=COUNTIFS('Game Log'!K2:K500,"=me",'Game Log'!F2:F500,"=Yuriko")
```

Then I just copy this for Winota too.

Now that I think about it, I'd love maybe a Stacked Chart that could stack the data more visually.

Solution (For Excel, not for Google Sheets):

Insert formula in A12 : `=TOROW(UNIQUE(A2:A7,FALSE),0,TRUE)&" Win %"` It will spill all unique characters in row. Insert formula in A13: `=TOROW(COUNTIFS(A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7),B2:B7,"me")/COUNTIF(A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7)))` it will spill win percentages in rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out in your sheets:

as shown in the screenshot, raw data is in columns A,B. I have the formula in cell D1

`=TRANSPOSE(BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),LAMBDA(ax,{ax&" Win %",TO_PERCENT(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A:A,A:A=ax,B:B="me")))/COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A:A,A:A=ax))))})))`

-

[image]

Comment: So I've tried to adapt this to my spreadsheet, but im having trouble.

Character is actually 'Game Log'!F and Winner is actually 'Game Log'!K

=TRANSPOSE(BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER('Game Log'!F2:Game Log'!F,'Game Log'!F2:Game Log'!F<>"")),LAMBDA(ax,{ax&" Win %",TO_PERCENT(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER('Game Log'!F:'Game Log'!F,'Game Log'!F:'Game Log'!F2=ax,'Game Log'!K:'Game Log'!K="me")))/COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER('Game Log'!F:'Game Log'!F,'Game Log'!F:'Game Log'!F=ax))))})))

I'm just getting a generic parsing error.

Comment: try: =TRANSPOSE(BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER('Game Log'!F2:F,'Game Log'!F2:F<>"")),LAMBDA(ax,{ax&" Win %",TO_PERCENT(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER('Game Log'!F:F,'Game Log'!F:F=ax,'Game Log'!K:K="me")))/COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER('Game Log'!F:F,'Game Log'!F:F=ax))))})))

Comment: I get the error "Result should be a single value"

Nevermind, I had formatting issues from Stackoverflow. This worked thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

To change columns into rows and vice versa you can use TRANSPOSE: `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A))`

And for the percentages you can use BYCOL to iterate through those values:

```
=BYCOL(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A)),LAMBDA(each, IFERROR(COUNTIFS(A2:A,each,B2:B,"me")/COUNTIF(A2:A,each))))
```